# PHP - dependency resolution

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php

I have some PHP applications that all share dependencies. Currently these are all baked directly into the applications, with no dependency resolution mechanism. This leads to essentially a mess of forked code that needs to be maintained separately and encourages bad practices like specific, rather than general, design. What I'd like to do for now is simply take some of my classes, move them into a namespace-like hierarchy (e.g. com.coolsoft.common, com.coolsoft.orm, com.coolsoft.widgets, etc.) and be able to declare a Composer-like dependency (namespace + version) in the project that uses those.

Composer seems a natural fit for this, but it seems to source everything from nebulous sources on GitHub or Packagist. Perhaps I can set up my own isolated Composer repositories and configure Composer to resolve these locally?

Comment: Have you read the [composer help on repositories](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md)? There is also [Toarn Proxy](https://toranproxy.com/) made by one of the composer developers.

Comment: Thank you, OIS. I read through the doc and I'm inclined to go with something like Satis.